# Accessing the navigation prop in React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, navigation, redux-form, redux-saga, react-navigation-v5

I have an app that is being updated from react navigation 2 to react navigation 5 and was wondering how to access the navigation prop outside of a screen component. For example in RN2 we were given NavigationActions which allowed us to do:

`import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
 NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName })`

This was helpful when dealing with a file that used redux-saga or redux-form as we could navigate based on the logic.

Is there something similar in RN5 I can use to make this possible?

Comment: So you need to pass navigation into redux action and inside that you can do `navigation.navigate('ScreenName)`

Comment: I was hoping there was an alternative solution to passing it in every action

Comment: same problem. same (no) solution yet.